# Passing Variable with space in title how do i

Tags: php, variables

First picture is my code.
I get the Category id "CatID" and Category Title "CatTitle" from the previous page
[image: My Code]
The results however does not display correctly when there is/are a space/'s in the title. How do i fix this ?

Any help appreciated
[image: The Results]
Thank you
Sam

Comment: you can use urlencode($string) and urldecode($string) functions. for your case urldecode($catTitle);

Comment: @Cavemanharris It looks like it's the ampersand causing problems, not the spaces. Ampersand separates URL parameters, so the value of `CatTitle` is `Home%20`, and then comes another parameter called `%20Garden`. As mentioned use `url(en|de)code()`. (Also, please *paste* code into questions; screenshots are just annoying.)

Answer (score 1):

you can use urlencode($string) and urldecode($string) functions.

for your case

```
$catTitle = urldecode($_GET['catTitle']);
```

%20 shows whenever there is space in URL stirng

Comment: Thank you kamlesh.bar, borjab and  Biffen. Between the three answers I have made it work!. Ta

Answer (score 1):

The "&" symbol is an example of special character in XML and HTML called [entities](http://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html_entities.asp) and must be translated to "&amp;"

Do use the [htmlentities funtion](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) to make the translation:

```
echo htmlentities($CatTitle);
```

**Update:** Also consider that the URL may be interpreted as if the $_GET["CatTitle"]="Home " and the $_GET[" Articles"] = null. May be it should be: CatTitle=Home%20&%20Garden in which case you may want to use URL encode while genereting the link.